How to loosen this nut?

I tried holding on to the rod with a monkey wrench/vise grip but it still turns when I try to turn the nut.

Have you tried to let the rod continue to turn, to see if it unscrews from the silver part?

If repair methods that involve gripping the rod with a tool or using power tools don't work for you, or if you feel they risk damage, you can use a nut splitter. It will destroy the nut but it should leave the threaded rod undamaged.


Photo credit: amazon.com
